# Creating a Trigger to Update Table on specific Value

Tags: sql, triggers

I am currently taking a database class and we need to involve some triggers in our database.
My group is making a Library database and need to make a trigger that when the value of an attribute DaysOut is "90". Another attribute called Fees will be increased to "10". Is this a possible trigger?
I wrote some syntax and sent it to my professor but gave me minimal advice. Here is the syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Late_Fee 
AFTER UPDATE OF DaysOut ON BOOKS 
WHEN DaysOut = 90 UPDATE CUSTOMERS 
SET Fees = Fees + 10 
WHERE Cust_ID = Cust_ID;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  I hate how collegiate Database courses go explicitly off the ANSI-SQL standard without any regard to an actual DBMS, because in such a scenario there is not a practical answer. The true answer to this question should be dependent on the DBMS in use, although there are many that may support similar syntax for trigger creation.

Comment: We really haven't established an actual DBMS. The book references Oracle throughout different chapters and then SQL-99. I assume its Oracle but this is my first Database course and am not entirely sure. Thank you for your response though!

Comment: It's likely ANSI-SQL 99. The book likely mentions Oracle because it is a popular DBMS historically. However, in my experience these types of book rarely show examples from actual DBMS systems (again, which is why I thoroughly hated the database course I took in college).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, the useful answer depends on the DBMS in use. Since this appears to be for a college course, you probably aren't using a DBMS and the answer is probably based on the ANSI-SQL standard rather than an actual SQL implementation. This is why I hate most collegiate database courses, because the professors usually go off a book that was written nearly 20 years ago instead of practical experience (I've often found that many professors teaching this type of course don't have any actual real database experience). I'd ask your professor what DBMS the answer is intended for. If the professor doesn't know, says to go off examples from your book, or says to use the ANSI-SQL standard, then this is a hypothetical question and there isn't a technically appropriate answer in my opinion (because even if there was a right answer, you'd have to change it to accommodate for the DBMS you're using).  Here are a few examples of how such a trigger could be implemented in real DBMS systems.

**My SQL**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
TRIGGER tr_Late_Fee AFTER UPDATE 
ON BOOKS 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF NEW.DaysOut = 90 THEN
        UPDATE CUSTOMERS 
        SET Fees = Fees + 10 
        WHERE Cust_ID = NEW.Cust_ID;
    END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Resources:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

Comment: The MySQL version looks a lot like the examples in the book, I am going to email my professor and see if this is acceptable. Thank you so much!

Comment: What if there are more than one rows in `inserted`?

Comment: @hatchet you're right about that situation and the sample code I quickly wrote for SQL-Server doesn't handle that particular scenario. In such an event the provided code would not function correctly (you'd actually get a SQL Exception). One way to handle this would be to create a cursor, which I'm sure goes far beyond the requirements of the OP. There are plenty of examples for how to write triggers in SQL Server. I don't have much time to go through and optimize this at the moment so I may exclude the SQL Server example if it bothers people.

Comment: The SQL-Server example has been excluded to avoid confusion, and since the OP is more concerned with ANSI-SQL syntax than an actual DBMS implementation, the mysql version appears to be more appropriate.

Comment: Rather than a cursor, this sort of trigger really should be done in a set based way, using just a single UPDATE that joins inserted to customers and include the DaysOut condition.

Comment: @hatchet I like that idea. It's best to avoid cursors when unnecessary.

Comment: @IsaacRendon if this is what you were looking for please mark the answer so the question can be resolved.